# I can't see messages sent to console via eclipse plugin code

Tags: eclipse, plugins, console

I'm working on some eclipse plugin using its IDE. My problem is printing something on console. For example, running the following command has not any result to be shown on console:

```
System.out.println("Some message!");
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A lot of the time Eclipse does not have a console open. Why do you want to write to the console?

Comment: @greg-449: I need it for debugging. I can't see whether the program halts successfully or abort because of some exception.

Comment: Use the Eclipse log via `Plugin.getLog` or `Platform.getLog`

Comment: @greg-449: Could you explain `Platform.getLog` more? Thanks.